# find kth smallest in bst using recursive inorder

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, inorder

I am trying to find the kth smallest in BST.

```
public void findKthSmallest(BSTNode<T> node, int k) {
    if(node == null) 
        return;
    findKthSmallest(node.left, k);

    count++;
    if (k == count) {
        System.out.println("Kth smallest: " + node.data);
        return;
    }
    findKthSmallest(node.right, k);
}
```

here count is a instance variable. I am not able to figure out how to implement it using count as a parameter(local varaible) in the function, since it get resets when function returns.

Any idea??

Answer (score 3):

Since this is Java and you have no pass by reference, I think the easiest is to modify `findKthSmallest` to return how many nodes are in the subtree rooted at `node`. Something like this:

```
public int findKthSmallest(BSTNode<T> node, int k) {
    if(node == null) 
        return 0;
    int left = findKthSmallest(node.left, k);

    if (k == left + 1) {
        System.out.println("Kth smallest: " + node.data);
        return 1;
    }

    return 1 + left + findKthSmallest(node.right, k);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to make a small correction in IVlad's approach. When we are searching left, the problem is to find kth smallest. However, when searching right we need to find k-left-1 (discarding the left subtree+current node). In java we cant return multiple values other than creating a class. So made a hack for that by passing an array as parameter. Here is the code:

```
public int kthSmallest(TreeNode node, int k, TreeNode kthNode[]) {
    int leftCount = 0;
    int rightCount = 0;
    if(node.left!=null) {
        leftCount = kthSmallest(node.left, k, kthNode);
    }
    if(leftCount==k-1) {
        kthNode[0] = node; // We can also return from here
    }
    if(node.right!=null) {
        rightCount = kthSmallest(node.right, k-leftCount-1, kthNode);
    }
    return leftCount + 1 + rightCount;
}

public TreeNode kthSmallest(TreeNode node, int k) {
    TreeNode kNode[] = new TreeNode[1];
    int nodeCount = kthSmallest(node, k, kNode);
    return kNode[0];
}
```